# Slider track visible behind slider thumb CSS

Tags: html, css, next.js

In the images below, or on https://archiemourad.vercel.app/ you can see that the slider track is visible behind the slider thumb. Images: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AACj.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF34k.png). My slider CSS looks like this:

```
input[type=range] {
    appearance: none;
    background: $Primary;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
}
input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* Chromium */
    width: 2px;
    height: 100px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid $Primary;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: $Primary;
}
// Mozilla being difficult
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid $Primary;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background: $Primary;
}
```

The code is also open source here: https://github.com/archiemourad/portfolio/blob/main/styles/globals.scss. I understand what's happening here, I've set the thumb to transparent, and it's doing exactly that. But I want to know how I could get this done, considering that there are changing images in the background. I just want the slider thumb to be transparent and **ignore** the slider track behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the top of my head: make the background image fixed and use it also for the thumb background. This will overlay the track in the back. I used the *shared bg* trick [here](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/mdGpPZj), check out `[shared-gradient]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I made recently. I may have an article for it soon to explain how it works

```css
input {
  --c: orange; /* active color */
  --g: 8px; /* the gap */
  --l: 5px; /* line thickness*/
  --s: 30px; /* thumb size*/
  
  width: 400px;
  height: var(--s); /* needed for Firefox*/
  -moz-appearance :none;
  appearance :none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
}

/* chromium */
input[type="range" i]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  height: var(--s);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--l) inset var(--c);
  border-image: linear-gradient(
    #0000 calc(50% - var(--l)/2),var(--c) 0 calc(50% + var(--l)/2),#0000 0) 
    1/0 100vw/0 calc(100vw + var(--g));
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  transition: .3s;
}
/* Firefox */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--s);
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--l) inset var(--c);
  border-image: linear-gradient(
    #0000 calc(50% - var(--l)/2),var(--c) 0 calc(50% + var(--l)/2),#0000 0) 
    1/0 100vw/0 calc(100vw + var(--g));
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

/**/
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 40px;
  place-content: center;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0 20px, #f9f9f9 0 40px)
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="20">

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" style="--c: lightblue;--l: 6px;--g:12px;">

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="70" style="--c: red;--l: 4px;">
```